# Gwt Sound doesn't work?

Tags: gwt, audio

I added zero code to my gwt.xml

```
<inherits name="org.miller.gwt.Sound"></inherits>
```

and then added 'gwt-sound.jar' to my project.

But when I'm going to run it, it shows zero error :

```
Loading modules
mysound.TestSound
  Loading inherited module 'org.miller.gwt.Sound'
     [WARN] Injected scripts no longer use an associated JavaScript block; ignoring.
```

Has anyone ever could use this library (gwt-sound)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/rcaloras/gwt-soundmanager2

Gwt-sound is dated, and doesn't work quite out of the box. Gwt-SoundManager2 is a recent fork of gwt-sound that is updated and well supported.